# Is there any way to create a screensaver for Android below 4.2

Tags: android, screensaver

Actually i want to create an app that starts displaying slide shows as soon as the system is about to sleep.

I know that there is a daydream kind of thing in Android 4.2 which i can use.
But i want to do this on a Android 4.1.2 device.
Is this possible ?

Comment: you can download screensaver app from Play Store and run with version 4.1 not 4.2, it runs OK. but it is not Daydream

Comment: Can you please provide the link of any such app on Play Store?

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.malamber.screensaver